# matlab function replacing last part of strings between known characters

Tags: string, matlab, function

I have  a text file TF including a set of the following kind of strings:

```
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north.airLeakage.senTem.T", 
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north.vol.Xi[1]", 
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.south.airLeakage.senTem.T",
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.south.vol.Xi[1]", " 
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north_ext.layMul.nMat[1].monoLayer1Nf.T[1]",
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north_ext.layMul.nMat[1].monoLayer2Nf.T[2]",
```

Given a line L, starting from the end let the substring s denote the portion of the  string  between  ,"  and the first .

To make it clearer,  for L=1: s=T, for L=2: s=Xi[1], for L=5: s=T[1], etc.

Given a text file  TF in the above format,  I want to write a MATLAB function which takes TF and replaces the corresponding  s  on each line with der(s).

For example, the function should change the above strings as follows:

```
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north.airLeakage.senTem.der(T)", 
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north.vol.der(Xi[1])", 
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.south.airLeakage.senTem.der(T)",
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.south.vol.der(Xi[1])", " 
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north_ext.layMul.nMat[1].monoLayer1Nf.der(T[1])",
"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north_ext.layMul.nMat[1].monoLayer2Nf.der(T[2])",
```

How can such a function be written?

Comment: Is TF the name of the text file, a cell array containing rows of the file, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there is a small `"` typo on the fourth line of your text file.  I'm going to remove this to make things simpler.

As such, the simplest way that I can see you do this is iterate through all of your strings, remove the single quotes, then find the point in your string where the last `.` occurs.  Extract this substring, then manually insert the `der()` in between this string.  Assuming that those strings are in a text file called `functions.txt`, you would read in your text file using [`textread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html) to read in individual strings.  As such:

```
names = textread('functions.txt', '%s');
```

`names` should now be a cell array of names where each element is each string encapsulated in double quotes.  Use [`findstr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findstr.html) to extract where the `.` is located, then extract the last location of where this is.  Extract this substring, then replace this string with `der()`.  In other words:

```
out_strings = cell(1, numel(names)); %// To store output strings
for idx = 1 : numel(names)
     %// Extract actual string without quotes and comma
     name_str = names{idx}(2:end-2);

     %// Find the last dot
     dot_locs = findstr(name_str, '.');

     %// Last dot location
     last_dot_loc = dot_locs(end);

     %// Extract substring after dot
     last_string = name_str(last_dot_loc+1:end);

     %// Create new string 
     out_strings{idx} = ['"' name_str(1:last_dot_loc) 'der(' last_string ')",'];
end
```

This is the output I get:

```
celldisp(out_strings)

out_strings{1} =

"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north.airLeakage.senTem.der(T)",


out_strings{2} =

"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north.vol.der(Xi[1])",


out_strings{3} =

"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.south.airLeakage.senTem.der(T)",


out_strings{4} =

"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.south.vol.der(Xi[1])",


out_strings{5} =

"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north_ext.layMul.nMat[1].monoLayer1Nf.der(T[1])",


out_strings{6} =

"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north_ext.layMul.nMat[1].monoLayer2Nf.der(T[2])",
```

---

The last thing you want to do is write each line of text to your text file.  You can use [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) to open up a file for writing.  `fopen` returns a file ID that is associated with the file you want to write to.  You then use [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to print your strings and name a newline for each string using this file ID.  You then close the file using [`fclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html) with this same file ID.  As such, if we wanted to output a text file called `functions_new.txt`, we would do:

```
%// Open up the file and get ID
fid = fopen('functions_new.txt', 'w');

%// For each string we have...
for idx = 1 : numel(out_strings)
    %// Write the string to file and make a new line
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', out_strings{idx});
end

%// Close the file
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: perfect! how can we write the out_strings to another text file called functions_new.txt?

Comment: @user3489173 - That's very easy.  You can use `fopen` and `fprintf`.  I'll write some code for you next.

Comment: @user3489173 - Done.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
regexprep(TF, '\.([^.]+)",$', '.der($1)",', 'dotexceptnewline', 'lineanchors')
```

It finds the longest sequence of non-dot characters appearing between a dot before and quote-comma-endline after, and encloses that inside `der(` `)`.

Comment: +1 - I couldn't figure out how to do it with regular expressions... not very well versed there.

Comment: wow I was struggling with regular expressions to find the correct syntax for a sequence of non-dot characters thanks! +1

Comment: @LuisMendo - Yup.. I didn't know that too.  I feel bad that the OP accepted my answer, but I guess he/she wanted a comprehensive solution that includes reading the file, processing the names, then writing to an output file... which I have.

Comment: @rayryeng Your answer is good too, and you took the time to explain everything. So don't feel bad :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it with `regexprep`:

```
str_out = regexprep(str_in, '\.([^\.]+)"$','\.der($1)"');
```

Example: for

```
str_in = {'"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north.airLeakage.senTem.T"' 
       '"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north.vol.Xi[1]"'};
```

this gives

```
str_out = 
    '"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north.airLeakage.senTem.der(T)"'
    '"linStru.twoZoneBuildingStructure.north.vol.der(Xi[1])"'
```